# How can I create an Amazon EventBridge schedule using the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-sdk-net

I want to schedule a task in AWS using C#.

Previously, I did this using EventBridge rules. However, with the introduction of the new EventBridge Scheduler functionality in AWS, I'd like to re-implement it.

Here's how I currently do it:

```cs
var putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest
{
    Name = ruleName,
    ScheduleExpression = cronExpression,
    State = isEnabled ? RuleState.ENABLED : RuleState.DISABLED,
    Description = "Demo",
};

var putRuleResponse = eventBridgeClient.PutRule(putRuleRequest);
```

My goal is to invoke a Lambda from the Scheduler.

How can I create an Amazon EventBridge schedule using the AWS SDK for .NET?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, what are your targets here? Can you share what you have so far as you mention the `CreateScheduleRequest` (which is on the right track)?

Comment: My final destination is to call a Lambda from the Scheduler as I use that from the old way. This is just that I want to use the new AWS scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a schedule for the Amazon EventBridge Scheduler, create a [`CreateScheduleRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Scheduler/TCreateScheduleRequest.html) and pass it to the [`CreateSchedule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Scheduler/MISchedulerCreateScheduleCreateScheduleRequest.html) method, part of the [`IAmazonScheduler`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Scheduler/TIScheduler.html) interface.

Make sure you have the the [`AWSSDK.Scheduler`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Scheduler) Nuget package installed for your project. As per the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSchedule.html), the following properties are required as a minimum:

- name
- schedule expression
- flexible time window
- target

*Note that you can no longer define the targets post schedule creation (like you could with rules) & that you must define a target at the time of creation.*

```cs
using Amazon.Scheduler;
using Amazon.Scheduler.Model;

var schedulerClient = new AmazonSchedulerClient();

var scheduleTimeWindow = new FlexibleTimeWindow
{
    Mode = FlexibleTimeWindowMode.OFF
};

var invokeLambdaTarget = new Target
{
    Arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:HelloWorld",
    RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SchedulerExecutionRole",
    Input = "{ 'Payload': 'TEST_PAYLOAD' }"
};

var createScheduleRequest = new CreateScheduleRequest
{
    Name = "MyDemoSchedule",
    ScheduleExpression = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)",
    State = ScheduleState.ENABLED,
    Description = "Demo description",
    FlexibleTimeWindow = scheduleTimeWindow,
    Target = invokeLambdaTarget
};

var createScheduleResponse =
    await schedulerClient.CreateScheduleAsync(createScheduleRequest);
```

Comment: Hi @Ermiya. how can I pass the value for FlexibleTimeWindow